# How to place navigation buttons on either side of an image in HTML

Tags: html, css

Please excuse my ignorance. I'm very new at writing HTML and couldn't find an answer on here to my question that I could understand, so I'm hoping someone can help me figure this out.

I'd like to add left and right arrow navigation buttons on either side of an image, but I can only get them (the buttons) to go over or under the image. I don't understand how to use CSS very well, but I think I may need to employ it in order to achieve the results I'm looking for, as HTML is pretty limited.

These are the buttons I am using:

```html
<form>
<button formaction="[link]">&#8592</button>
    <button formaction="[link]">&#8594</button>
</form>
```

And here is the image (I know the code is a mess, I apologize for that)

```html
<p><a href="/beats" target="_self"><img class="alignleft size-full wp-image-1660" height="400" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/46/Gray492.png" style="max-width: calc(100% - 14px); border: 0px solid #000000; padding: 0px; margin: 0.4em auto 1.625em; display: block; clear: both; width: auto;" /></a></p>
```

Any help or ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this:

HTML:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn--left">&#8592</button>
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/46/Gray492.png" class="img" />
<button  type="button" class="btn btn--right">&#8594</button>
```

CSS:

```
HTML {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*, *::before, *::after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}


.img{
  max-width: 100px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.btn {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Example in [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ewr54feq/1/)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you may try this:

```css
img{
  width: 80px;
  float: left;
}
.button-left{
  float: left;
}

.button-right{
  float: left;
}

button{
  margin-top: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<button class="button-left">Left</button>
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/46/Gray492.png">
<button class="button-right">Right</button>
```